# PHP array_multisort by key ascending

Tags: php, sorting

**How do I sort an array by a specific key?** I've got `$my_array`, how do I sort it ascending by the `distance` key? Data itself mostly irrelevant and reduced for the sake of simplicity.

```
[0083] => Array
    (
     [distance] => 28
     [url] => http://example.com/
    )

[0087] => Array
    (
     [distance] => 30
     [url] => http://example.com/
    )

[008e] => Array
    (
     [distance] => 34
     [url] => http://example.com/
    )
```

---

Error message *Message: Cannot use a scalar value as an array* where `$distance[$k]  = $v['distance'];` below:

```
    foreach ($my_array as $k => $v)
    {
        $distance[$k]  = $v['distance'];
        $url[$k] = $v['url'];
    }

    array_multisort($distance, SORT_ASC, $url, SORT_ASC, $my_array);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($my_array);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
<?php
$data[] = array('distance' => 34, 'url' => 'http://example.com/');
$data[] = array('distance' => 30, 'url' => 'http://example.com/');
$data[] = array('distance' => 28, 'url' => 'http://example.com/');

$distance = array();
$url = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $distance[$key]  = $row['distance'];
    $url[$key] = $row['url'];
}

array_multisort($distance, SORT_ASC, $url, SORT_ASC, $data);

echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distance] => 28
            [url] => http://example.com/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [distance] => 30
            [url] => http://example.com/
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [distance] => 34
            [url] => http://example.com/
        )        
)
```

Comment: as of PHP 5.5.0 you can use `array_column()` instead of loop, like `$distance = array_column($data, 'distance');`

Answer (score 3):

Use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

Pseudo code:

```
function sortfunc($a,$b)
{
    return $a['distance'] < $b['distance'] ? -1 : $a['distance'] == $b['distance'] ? 0 : 1;
}

usort($yourArray, 'sortfunc');
```

flip 1 and -1 to change sort order.

Comment: Eh...trying to use native PHP function here... I'll test yours though I'm trying to learn the native function.

Comment: usort is a native function, it lets you create a function that weighs your array elements. There is no native function to do exactly what you want.